# Setting attributes on anonymous objects

Tags: c#

I thought this was possible in c# .net 2.0 ?

```
header.Cells.Add((new TableCell(){Text = "First header"}));
```

unless I am doing it wrong? this produces the following error:

```
CS1026: ) expected
```

Were is the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property initializer syntax was introduced in C# 3.0; it is not valid syntax in C# 2.0.

Comment: I guess it would explain why it doesn't work, are there any other methods available short of declaring everything ?

Comment: @Enriquev: If you control the type, you can define a constructor that takes values for whatever properties you'd like to set. Apart from that, unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about C# 2.0... but in C# 3.0 you can do this instead:

```
header.Cells.Add((new TableCell{ Text = "First header" }));
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure using parentheses to call the constructor is still valid when using this syntax.

Comment: @Andrew: Valid and, I believe, required.

Comment: Sorry but this gives the following error : "CS1526: A new expression requires () or [] after type"

Comment: @Andrew: I've removed the bit about parentheses. They are, in fact, allowed.

Comment: @Adam: For classes with a default constructor, they're optional.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can set the properties in the declaration in 2.0. So you will have to do:

```
TableCell tc=new TableCell();
tc.Text = "First header";
header.Cells.Add(tc);
```

Answer (score 0):

The support for this syntax is provided by the **compiler**, not the .Net runtime / CLR.

If you are using Visual Studio 2008 or later you can use this syntax perfectly fine while targeting .Net 2.0, if not then you will need to do this the "normal" way.

Also you have an additional pair of redundant parentheses - you may find it easier to use the following layout when using this syntax:

```
header.Cells.Add(new TableCell() 
{
    Text = "First header" 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not an anonymous object, `TableCell` is a predefined type. You're referring to implicit object initialization syntax which was introduced in [C# 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364047%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#cs3spec_topic5), you'll have to do it the "old fashioned" way.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up, I am bad at using the correct terms because English is not my first language, at least the code speaks for itself.

Comment: The confusion here is that "anonymous object" isn't really a term. Anonymous types refer to types created and used within the confines of a single function and have no name that's visible at compile time. Anonymous methods refer to functions that are defined within another function and also have no compile-time name. "Anonymous object", as far as I am aware, has no definition.

Comment: @Adam Agreed on the nit-point, however I was using the term the OP used as he may refer to compiler inferred types as "anonymous objects", as technically they are indeed compiler generated types, however once instantiated, IMHO, it wouldn't be "wrong" to call them "anonymous objects" (as in, an actual instance of an anonymous type).

Comment: @Brandon: I think the OP was referring to them as "anonymous objects" because there was no explicit variable declared to hold the new reference to the `TableCell` (he's passing the new reference directly to a function).

Comment: @Adam Ahhh, yeah I see your point now. Once again I let logic get in they way of my clairvoyance. P.S., cheers from Charlotte.